# Core Data: Update an NSManagedObject with the option to fall back to it's original state

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

Consider a managed object with a set of properties A which have to be replaced with a set of properties B. However, the mechanism to retrieve the information for B is not fail-safe (e.g. if there is a failing network connection) and there is a chance that B cannot be fully constructed. In this case, I need to fall back to the state of object A to maintain consistency.
What is the best Core Data pattern to realize a fail safe, consistent update mechanism in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you send the `save:` selector to the `NSManagedObjectContext` object, none of your changes are persisted.  Once 'saved' you have created a 'commit point'.  If you want to roll back any changes you have made since the last commit point in core data send the `rollback` selector to your `NSManagedObjectContext`.  You will need to check for successful outcome of your network activity and send either `save:` or `rollback` depending on the final outcome.